# Getting webpack compilation error in cypress when running in Jenkins

Tags: .net, git, model-view-controller, cypress

I'm getting webpack compilation error for all my cypress test cases when running in Jenkins. In local it's working fine.
[image]

I've tried several ways to resolve this, like adding webpack-preprocessor and adding .babelrc files but nothing seems to be working for me.

My dependencies:

"@babel/core": "^7.19.3",

"@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.3",

"@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^5.12.2",

"@testing-library/dom": "^8.17.1",

"@types/node": "^15.3.0",

"axios": "^0.21.1",

"babel-loader": "^8.2.5",

"cy-verify-downloads": "^0.1.6",

"cypress": "^8.4.0",

"cypress-file-upload": "^5.0.8",

"cypress-mochawesome-reporter": "^2.0.1",

"cypress-ntlm-auth": "3.2.3",

"fs-extra": "^10.0.0",

"mssql": "^7.3.0",

"pdf-parse": "^1.1.1",

"typescript": "^4.2.4",

"v1sdk": "^2.3.1",

"webpack": "^5.74.0"

"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1",

"eslint": "^8.23.1",

"webpack-config": "^7.5.0"

Please help me with this. Let me know if you need any more code for this.

Comment: I'm facing the same error. were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: nope I haven't yet